# native element not defined when ngSwitch condition in canvas element

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, chart.js

I am working with chart.js in my ionic 2 application if i implement canvas element with out ngSwitch condition for rendering it works fine but when i use condition i got error with native element not defined so canvas element not rendered because canvas element not ready at the time of subscribe chart data. how can i solve this.

```
  @ViewChild('todayChart') todayChart;
 @ViewChild('yesterdayChart') yesterdayChart;

ionViewWillEnter() {

     this.homeauth.todaychart().subscribe((table) => {
         var labels = [], datay = [], datum = [], timestamp = [];
         for (var i = 0; i <= table.length - 1; i++) {
             datum.push(table[i].chartdate);
             labels.push(table[i].z10s3);
             datay.push(table[i].z10s6);
             timestamp.push(table[i].timestamp);
         }

         this.heutechart = new Chart(this.todayChart.nativeElement, {
             type: 'line',
             data: {
                 xLabels: labels,
                 datasets: [
                     {
                         label: 'G.Oil', fill: true, lineTension: 0.1, backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)", borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                         pointHoverBorderWidth: 2, pointRadius: 1, pointHitRadius: 10, data: datay, spanGaps: false,
                     }
                 ],

             },
         });
     });

     this.homeauth.yesterdaychart().subscribe((table) => {
         var labels = [], datay = [], datum = [];
         for (var i = 0; i <= table.length - 1; i++) {
             datum.push(table[i].chartdate);
             labels.push(table[i].z10s3);
             datay.push(table[i].z10s6);
         }

         this.vortagschart = new Chart(this.yesterdayChart.nativeElement, {

             type: 'line',
             data: {
                 xLabels: labels,
                 datasets: [
                     {
                         label: 'G.Oil', fill: true, lineTension: 0.1, backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)", borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                         pointHoverBorderWidth: 2, pointRadius: 1, pointHitRadius: 10, data: datay, spanGaps: false,
                     }
                 ],

             }
         });
     });


 } 

html:

 <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="category">
    <ion-segment-button value="today"> 24h </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="yesterday"> 48h </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>

<div [ngSwitch]="category">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'today'">
    <canvas #yesterdayChart> </canvas>
  </div>
</div>

<div [ngSwitch]="category">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'yesterday'">
    <canvas #todayChart></canvas> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont have to use `ng-switch` for *each case*.

It should be like so:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="category">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'today'"> <!-- case 1 -->
    <canvas #yesterdayChart> </canvas>
  </div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'yesterday'">
    <canvas #todayChart></canvas> <!-- case 2 -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Add if conditions in the component since only one of these elements will be present in the DOM.

```
if(this.todayChart){
  this.heutechart = new Chart(this.todayChart.nativeElement, {
             type: 'line',
             data: {
                 xLabels: labels,
                 datasets: [
                     {
                         label: 'G.Oil', fill: true, lineTension: 0.1, backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)", borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                         pointHoverBorderWidth: 2, pointRadius: 1, pointHitRadius: 10, data: datay, spanGaps: false,
                     }
                 ],

             },
         });
     });
  }
 //Similarly for yesterdayChart
```

Comment: I tried like that but that is not the problem i got error like cannot read property native element undefined

Comment: hmm.. your view is loading later.. you could try other [lifecyclehooks](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/) `ionViewDidEnter` ..

Comment: Thank you but i try with all possible lifecycles.

Comment: you need to put the nativeelement call in an if condition though.. only one div will be there because of the switch case. So the other could be throwing exception?

Comment: Did you mean like this  `<div [ngSwitch]="category">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'today'">
    <div *ngIf="heutechart">
    <canvas #todayChart> </canvas>
     </div>
      <div *ngIf="vortagschart">
    <canvas #yesterdayChart> </canvas>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>`